# Keep getting a value error too many values to unpack(1)

Tags: python

Keep getting this error when trying to convert data in a database table to a JSchart using json. Not sure what to make of this error, kept me idle for a couple of hours. I would also like to note that the graph  doesn't display a pie chart as well when given raw data. I do have a canvas above as well

```
@add_dash.route('/chart')
def chart():
    income_vs_expenses = db.session.query(db.func.sum(IncomeExpenses.amount),
    IncomeExpenses.type).group_by(IncomeExpenses.type).order_by(IncomeExpenses.type).all()

    income_expenses = []
    for total_amount, in income_vs_expenses:
        income_expenses.append(total.amount)


    return render_template("chart.html", user=current_user, income_vs_expenses = json.dumps(income_expenses))
```

My javascipt

```
{% block javascript %}

<script> 
    let income_expenses = JSON.parse({{ income_vs_expenses| tojson }})
    let income_vs_expense_chart = new Chart(income_vs_expenses, {
        type: 'pie',
        data: {
            labels: ['expense', 'income'],
            datasets: [{
                label: "Income Vs Expenses",
                data: income_expenses,
                backgroundColor: ['#5DA5DA ', '#FAA43A', '#60BD68',
                    '#B276B2', '#E16851', '#FB8267'],

                borderWidth: 1,
                hoverBorderColor: "black",
                hoverBorderWidth: 2,
                hoverBackgroundColor: 'rgba(154, 245, 140)',
                pointHoverRadius: 5
            }],
        },
        options: {
            title: {
                display: true,
                text: "Income Vs Expenses",
                fontSize: 20,
            },
            legend: {
                position: "right",
                labels: {
                    fontColor: "blue"
                },
                display: true,
            },

            elements: {
                hitRadius: 3,
            }
        }
    })
</script>
 


{% endblock %}
```

full traceback

```
File "C:\Users\Cbcbc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2095, in __call__
    def __call__(self, environ: dict, start_response: t.Callable) -> t.Any:
        """The WSGI server calls the Flask application object as theOpen an interactive python shell in this frame
        WSGI application. This calls :meth:`wsgi_app`, which can be
        wrapped to apply middleware.
        """
        return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
File "C:\Users\Cbcbc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2080, in wsgi_app
            try:
                ctx.push()
                response = self.full_dispatch_request()
            except Exception as e:
                error = e
                response = self.handle_exception(e)
            except:  # noqa: B001
                error = sys.exc_info()[1]
                raise
            return response(environ, start_response)
        finally:
File "C:\Users\Cbcbc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2077, in wsgi_app
        ctx = self.request_context(environ)
        error: t.Optional[BaseException] = None
        try:
            try:
                ctx.push()
                response = self.full_dispatch_request()
            except Exception as e:
                error = e
                response = self.handle_exception(e)
            except:  # noqa: B001
                error = sys.exc_info()[1]
File "C:\Users\Cbcbc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1525, in full_dispatch_request
            request_started.send(self)
            rv = self.preprocess_request()
            if rv is None:
                rv = self.dispatch_request()
        except Exception as e:
            rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
        return self.finalize_request(rv)
 
    def finalize_request(
        self,
        rv: t.Union[ResponseReturnValue, HTTPException],
File "C:\Users\Cbcbc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1523, in full_dispatch_request
        self.try_trigger_before_first_request_functions()
        try:
            request_started.send(self)
            rv = self.preprocess_request()
            if rv is None:
                rv = self.dispatch_request()
        except Exception as e:
            rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
        return self.finalize_request(rv)
 
    def finalize_request(
File "C:\Users\Cbcbc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1509, in dispatch_request
            getattr(rule, "provide_automatic_options", False)
            and req.method == "OPTIONS"
        ):
            return self.make_default_options_response()
        # otherwise dispatch to the handler for that endpoint
        return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**req.view_args)
 
    def full_dispatch_request(self) -> Response:
        """Dispatches the request and on top of that performs request
        pre and postprocessing as well as HTTP exception catching and
        error handling.
File "C:\Users\Cbcbc\Desktop\StCh\website\add_dash.py", line 56, in chart
    income_vs_expenses = db.session.query(db.func.sum(IncomeExpenses.amount),
    IncomeExpenses.type).group_by(IncomeExpenses.type).order_by(IncomeExpenses.type).all()
 
    income_expenses = []
    for total_amount in income_vs_expenses:
        income_expenses.append(total.amount)
 
 
    return render_template("chart.html", user=current_user, income_vs_expenses = json.dumps(income_expenses))
```

Comment: Post the full traceback.

Comment: in the line `for total_amount, in income_vs_expenses:`, you shouldn't have a comma after `total_amount`.

Comment: it says that total needs to be defined after that

Comment: posted the full traceback

Answer (score 0):

you have to remove the comma after total_amount in the for loop

Comment: I have and it then gives me a name error NameError: name 'total' is not defined

Comment: Probably you should change total.amount into total_amount in the line below the previous correction

Comment: that did actually sort it, im getting a new error now TypeError: Object of type Row is not JSON serializable

Comment: I'll just trace back